# How to avoid circular import (dependency) in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import, dependency-management

I have a simple example where I have a circular dependency issue. What can be done to avoid this importing loop?

store.js

```
import { fetchApi } from "./api";

class Store {
  auth = "zzzzz";

  fetch = () => fetchApi();
}

const store = new Store();
export default store;
```

api.js

```
import client from "./client";

export const fetchApi = () => client("/test");
```

client.js

```
import store from "./store";

const client = (endpoint) => {
  const config = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${store.auth}`
    }
  };

  return window.fetch(endpoint, config);
};

export default client;
```

With this code, I have the following situation:

- store is importing api
- api is importing client
- client is importing store

store -> api -> client -> store

Happy to hear suggestions or see examples on how can I avoid this pattern.

Comment: It is helpful to define the responsibility of each package first.

Comment: For eg., to me it is not clear why Store uses `fetchApi`

Comment: api.js is responsible for making the api requests.
store.js is responsible for the business logic
client.js is the utility function that actually handles the requests, used by other api requests

Comment: It might be good if the Store did not fetch the data, instead it should receive the data and store it.

Answer (score 1):

since JS import has not this feature (at this date, at least), you have to remove the loop

there are various ways, for instance:

- moving out a shared, stateless logic to a new file
- moving the looped logic in the caller
- making the called abstract and passing a parameter (which contains the looping relationship) from the called

and others